# How to convert SQL query to key-value command

Tags: sql, database, tidb

Is it possible to use some opensource project to help parse the sql query and convert it into the custom key-value db command (CRUD on the key). I saw the architecture of the tidb, and it seems like they have an abstracted layer. I would appreciated anyone pointing to some resources to help start the process.

I did try to research other project out there, and it seems like most of them have ad-hoc and embeded the parsing layers into their db, so I cannot really decouple and use their solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this blog:https://www.pingcap.com/blog/tidb-internal-computing/

But I don't think it is easy to decouple the code from TiDB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an SQL parser like https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/tree/master/parser but then you would have to add something that does the actual storage operations.

If you want transactions you might want to check this:
https://tikv.org/deep-dive/distributed-transaction/percolator/